# PHP session timer is ignored

Tags: php, authentication

this is the script im using for a login function. But if i want to add a timer to the session, it ignores it. I have tried it on 10 seconds, or 1 minute. But it does not seem to work. Someone has an idea of what is going wrong?

this is the line of code im using for the timer : `session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");`

Thanks in forehand.

```
public function login($username, $password) {
        $salt="";
        $this->user_id=0;
        $this->status=0;
        $salt_query=$this->mysqli->query(
<<<EOT
            SELECT salt
            FROM xxxxx
            WHERE username="{$username}"
EOT
        );
        $salt_query = $salt_query->fetch_row();
        $salt = $salt_query[0];

        $hash = hash('sha512', $password.= $salt);

        $result = $this->mysqli->query(
<<<EOT
            SELECT werknemer_id,status
            FROM xxxxx
            WHERE username="{$username}" AND password="{$hash}"
EOT
        );

        $rij =$result->fetch_row();
        if ((empty($rij)) || (empty($rij[0]))) return(1);// Invalid combination


        if (($rij[1]<1) || ($rij[1]>2)){
            return(2); // Inactive account
        }
        $this->user_id=intval($rij[0]);
        $this->status=intval($rij[1]);

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['werknemer_id']=$this->user_id;
        session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
        return(0); // login
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual.  I havent used it but it does say that you have to use it in every script.  Also, you have to do it before start_session.  I think that on of these is your problem.

> Set cookie parameters defined in the `php.ini` file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call `session_set_cookie_params()` for every request and before `session_start()` is called.

[Reference](https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).